# getting null pointer exception in this code

Tags: android

```
  public class StartDraw extends Activity  {




@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // setContentView(R.layout.main);
    MyView view1 =new MyView(this);
   // view1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    setContentView(view1);



}


 public class MyView extends View implements OnTouchListener{
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams LP;  
    ViewGroup dlayout; 
      ImageView[] ActionI = new ImageView[4];
      ImageView[] ReciverI = new ImageView[4];
    public MyView(Context c) {
        super(c);
     //  dlayout = new ViewGroup(c); // if i use this then error shown {Cannot instantiate the type ViewGroup}
         LP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
       //  ViewGroup dlayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.dlayout);
         dlayout.setLayoutParams(LP); // at this position gettting null pointer exception

}

   @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
           paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
           paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
           paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
           canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);

           canvas.drawLine(offset_x, offset_y, currentX, currentY, paint);

    }
}
```

Comment: I initalize , but error is shown

Comment: why have you commented out ViewGroup dlayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.dlayout);?

Comment: @Premsuraj , because I'm not extends Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setContentView(R.layout.main); remove this comments and enable it

```
   setContentView(R.layout.main); remove this comments and enable it
```

setContentView(R.layout.main); remove this comments and enable it

Answer (score 0):

You have commented out the `dlayout` initialization. Hence it is null. Causing a *NullPointerException* in `dlayout.setLayoutParams`.

If there is something about this cause/effect that you are not understanding, please extend your question to clarify. If, however, you are unsure how to initialize the dlayout variable, ***make that into a question of it's own***.

Answer (score 0):

You try to set a Property of an Object which is not initialized

```
dlayout.setLayoutParams(LP);
```

Uncomment your code above and the Error should be fixed.

```
//  ViewGroup dlayout = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.dlayout);
```

Comment: I'm not using extends Activity, then how can i use this

Comment: You can also use the findViewByID method if you extends the View. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Comment: at this position i'm facing same problem {Null Pointer exception}

Comment: You have to ensure that a View with id = dlayout exists like android:id="@+id/dlayout", if not all the time findViewByID would return NULL

Comment: thats y i was saying, at where i will get R.id.dlayout.... i am not extends Activity

Comment: In layout i have  android:id="@+id/dlayout"